# How can I run the Parent Component's (`App.js`) Function named fakeAuth.authenticate from the Child component (`LoginApp`)?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to call the parent component `App.js` fakeAuth.authenticate function from child componenet `LoginApp.js`.

Do I need to set state on the parent to redirect Child's PrivateRoute?

Most of my authentication is happening in Server side. I am just using React router to protect my protected page.

Will appreciate if you can show me the way here.

Below is the code:

```
// Parent Componenet

const fakeAuth = {
isAuthenticated: false,
 authenticate(cb) {
this.isAuthenticated = true
setTimeout(cb, 100) // fake async
}
 }

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
  fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
  ?<Component {...props}/>
  :<Redirect to='/'/>
  )} />
)


 class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <Router>
       <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={LoginApp} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
    </div>
  </Router>
   );
 }
 }

export default App;



// Child Component

const LoginApp = (props) => {

 const loginWasClickedCallback = (data) => {
console.log(data);
// alert('Login callback, see log on the console to see the data.');

axios.post('/api/account/signin', data)
  .then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.data.success) {

      // !!! WANT TO CALL PARENT'S AUTHENTICATE FUNCTION HERE !!!

    } else {
      props.history.push('/');
      alert(res.data.message);
    }
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    // console.log(err);
  });
 };

  return (
     <div className="loginWrapper">
  <ReactSignupLoginComponent
    title="Welcome to KidKlub!"
    handleSignup={signupWasClickedCallback}
    handleLogin={loginWasClickedCallback}
  />
     </div>
  );

 };

  export default withRouter(LoginApp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
// in parent
<Route exact path="/" component={() => <LoginApp authenticate={fakeAuth.authenticate} />} />
// in child component run function
props.authenticate(args);
```

Comment: args is just an example. Your arguments of function will be here